# How we can get script response methods on runtime in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am calling a script URL in the response I need to use the response which contains a method. I need to implement that method in my code. Please suggest if anybody has the solution

I have the below URL and I calling script URL in Directive

```
script URL = https://botsrv.com/qb/widget/xxxxx/xxxxx
```

This is my Directive -

```
directive('demo',[ function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, el , attrs) 

            var scriptElem = angular.element(document.createElement('script'));
            scriptElem.attr("src", 'https://botsrv.com/qb/widget/xxxxxx/xxxxx'); // set var appropriately
            el.append(scriptElem);

        }
    };
}])
```

the script having onSave method
This is the method - I need the results from the onSave function in my JS Controller.

```
onSave: function (results) {
    console.log('onSave method ---- ' , results);
 }
```

Comment: I think you won't be very much happy reading yourself in 3 years. I read over and over and it doesn't make much sense to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Tell us what library you are trying to inject, there really is not enough information here for anyone to help you. The fact that there is some "onSave" method implies that the script adds some key to the wndow object. If that is the case you should encapsulate that in a factory or service and inject that service/factory into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use response of this function

```
onSave: function (results) {
    console.log('onSave method ---- ' , results);
}
```

so you have to use variable or $scope to capture result of this function.

```
ScriptApp.controller('scriptController', function($scope, demo){
    $scope.result = [];
    $scope.getListUsers = function(){
        demo.OnSave().then(function(response){
            $scope.result = response.data.result;
        });
    }
});
```

by above method you can get response of function in controller.